# Virtual Reality (2.82), Scene Inspection: how to enable it?

Tags: rendering, customization

Following the 2.82 [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/UI), in the *"Preferences"* section of this link, I effectively have the *"experimental"* tab but it is empty.

How can I have the virtual reality options enabled?

In the release notes documentation:

[image]

What I have on my computer (PC laptop, Asus Geforce rtx graphic card):

[image]